# Open programs at random time with applescript

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I was wondering how I can make a harmless "fake" virus to prank a friend. I am using Applescript Editor. The prank is going to open Safari at any random time. I know how to open Safari with Applescript but it's the random part i don't know how to do.

If someone knows how I can do it PLEASE tell me.

Comment: For me, it's easier in a shell.  'sleep' and '$RANDOM'

Comment: Hopefully you will get a more complete answer.  I cannot be more specific without opening Terminal on the Mac (I am on iPad now).  But those are not Applescript, they are Unix shell.  When I get back to my Mac, if there is not already an answer, I will post.

Comment: Tank You <3 @WGroleau

Answer (score 1):

Use `random number from __ to __` and ifs.

For example:

```
repeat
    if random number from 0 to 100 = 0 then
        #do thing
    end if
    delay 60
end repeat
```

Comment: Looks like an answer, so I can stop feeling guilty about not being able to get on my Mac.  :-)

Comment: @WGroleau glad to hear it :)

Comment: Thanx everyone... U r the best @JMY1000

Comment: @H.Höglund Awesome! Don't forget to mark it as solved.